# Super Folding Numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, binary, bitwise

We have already defined a folding number [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/95458/folding-numbers).

But now we are going to define a Super Folding Number.  A Super Folding number is a number that if folded enough times it will eventually reach one less than a power of two.  The method of folding is slightly different than in the folding number question.

The folding algorithm goes as follows:

- Take the binary representation

  e.g. 5882

  ```
  1011011111010
  ```
- Spilt it into three partitions.  First half, last half and middle digit (iff it has a odd number of digits)

  ```
  101101 1 111010
  ```
- If the middle digit is zero this number cannot be folded
- Reverse the second half and superimposed on the first half

  ```
  010111
  101101
  ```
- Add the digits in place

  ```
  111212
  ```
- Iff there are any 2s in the result the number cannot be folded otherwise the new number is the result of the folding algorithm.

A number is a Super Folding number if it can be folded to a continuous string of ones. (All Folding numbers are also Super Folding Numbers)

Your task is to write code that takes in a number and outputs a truthy value if the number is a Super Folding number and falsy otherwise.  You will be scored on the size of your program.

### Examples

#### 5200

Convert to binary:

```
1010001010000
```

Split in half:

```
101000 1 010000
```

The middle is one so we continue
Superimpose the halves:

```
000010
101000
```

Added them:

```
101010
```

No twos so we continue
Split in half:

```
101 010
```

Fold:

```
010
101

111
```

The result is `111` (7 in decimal) so this is a Super Folding Number.

### Test Cases

The first 100 Super Folding Numbers are:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20, 22, 28, 31, 34, 38, 42, 48, 52, 56, 63, 74, 78, 90, 104, 108, 120, 127, 128, 130, 132, 142, 150, 160, 170, 178, 192, 204, 212, 232, 240, 255, 272, 274, 276, 286, 310, 336, 346, 370, 400, 412, 436, 472, 496, 511, 516, 518, 524, 542, 558, 580, 598, 614, 640, 642, 648, 666, 682, 704, 722, 738, 772, 796, 812, 852, 868, 896, 920, 936, 976, 992, 1023, 1060, 1062, 1068, 1086, 1134, 1188, 1206, 1254, 1312, 1314, 1320, 1338, 1386, 1440, 1458, 1506, 1572, 1596]
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, how did `3` sneak into the test cases again? I can't see how it can be folded, since it splits to `1 1`, immediately giving a `2`. Or are you saying that folding it zero times counts also?

Comment: @geobits 3 is supposed to be there. I checked this time ;). Three is 11 so it gets to only ones in zero files

Comment: I think it may be worth putting a note right near the top, just after you link to the other folding number question that points out that the individual folds in this question will use a different method.

Answer (score 9):

Here's my first ever shot at code golf:

## Python 3, 167 bytes

167 bytes if tabs or single spaces are used for indentation

```
def f(n):
 B=bin(n)[2:];L=len(B);M=L//2
 if'1'*L==B:return 1
 S=str(int(B[:M])+int(B[:-M-1:-1]))
 return 0if(~L%2==0and'0'==B[M])or'2'in S else{S}=={'1'}or f(int(S,2))
```

Edit: Thanks to everyone's help below, the code above has been reduced from an original size of 232 bytes!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can save a bunch of bytes  by removing the spaces after the `:`s, and returning `0` and `1` instead of `True` and `False`.

Comment: Thank you Steven. Also, I'm not 100% sure I counted the byte length correctly.

Comment: I'm seeing [232](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#def%20f%28n%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20B%3Dbin%28n%29%5B2%3A%5D%0A%20%20%20%20L%3Dlen%28B%29%0A%20%20%20%20M%3DL%2F%2F2%0A%20%20%20%20if%20B%3D%3D%271%27%2aL%3A%20return%20True%0A%20%20%20%20S%3Dstr%28int%28B%5B%3AM%5D%29%2Bint%28B%5B%3A-M-1%3A-1%5D%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28~L%252%3D%3D0%20and%20%270%27%3D%3DB%5BM%5D%29%20or%20%272%27%20in%20S%3A%20return%20False%0A%20%20%20%20if%20S%3D%3D%271%27%2alen%28S%29%3A%20return%20True%0A%20%20%20%20return%20f%28int%28S%2C2%29%29) bytes.  Give me a second and I can try to golf it a little further.

Comment: I used this to measure: http://bytesizematters.com/

Comment: When I checked it just now with Sublime Text 3 I got 232.

Comment: I was able to get it down to [201](http://pastebin.com/4n4H2EzA) with some simple optimizations.

Comment: @Kapocsi, [bytesizematters.com](http://bytesizematters.com/) counts newlines wrong. Compare with [mothereff.in](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A), 5 digits and 5 newlines should be 10 bytes, not the 14 I got on bytesize... its 232.

Comment: Some spaces can be removed: `if B=='1'*L:return 1`->`if'1'*L==B:return 1`; `0 and`->`0and`; `) or`->`)or`. First few lines of the function can be meged with `;`. Also you can use the fact that the set of digits will be `{'1'}` to avoid `len(S)` and then merge the last to lines to `return{S}=={'1'}or f(int(S,2))`; then merge the new last two lines to `return 0if(~L%2==0and'0'==B[M])or'2'in S else{S}=={'1'}or f(int(S,2))`. This all takes you down to [167 bytes](http://ideone.com/OHfPDM). You could save more by moving to Python 2 where `str()` can be replaced by backticks, `\`\``

Comment: ...and welcome to ṖṖCG!

Comment: what purpose does `{S}=={'1'}` serve? How is it different from `S=='1'`?

Comment: @Kapocsi I managed an even shorter, pretty confusing, doubly recursive version :)

Comment: @Cyoce `{S}` makes a set from the string `S` (if it is non-empty) and `{'1'}` makes one from the string `'1'`, so if `S` only contains the character `'1'` the two sets will be equal. That is if `S='111'` (7) this will evaluate to `True` whereas `S=='1'` would not.

Comment: @JonathanAllan That's pretty cool.  Cryptic.  You're referencing your python 2 post, right?

Comment: @Kapocsi I am indeed. I've never used that mod 2 hack to bypass a logical or before, but it works a charm; flash of inspiration.

Answer (score 5):

### Java 7, 202 bytes

```
boolean g(Integer a){byte[]b=a.toString(a,2).getBytes();int i=0,l=b.length,o=0,c,z=(a+1&a)==0?-1:1;for(;i<l/2&z>0;o+=o+c*2,z*=c>1|(l%2>0&b[l/2]<49)?0:1)c=b[i]+b[l-++i]-96;return z<0?1>0:z<1?0>1:g(o/2);}
```

It took a bit of effort to make the old folding function recursable, but here it is. It's ugly as sin, to be honest. I'll have to take a look in the morning to see if I can golf it further, since I can barely stand to look at it right now.

With line breaks:

```
boolean g(Integer a){
    byte[]b=a.toString(a,2).getBytes();
    int i=0,l=b.length,o=0,c,z=(a+1&a)==0?-1:1;
    for(;i<l/2&z>0;o+=o+c*2,z*=c>1|(l%2>0&b[l/2]<49)?0:1)
        c=b[i]+b[l-++i]-96;
    return z<0?1>0:z<1?0>1:g(o/2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), <s>47</s> 44 bytes

```
ri2b{_W%.+__0e=)\_,1>\0-X+:*3<*&}{_,2/<}w2-!
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cmkyYntfVyUuK19fMGU9KVxfLDE-XDAtWCs6KjM8KiZ9e18sMi88fXcyLSE&input=MTU5Ng) or [generate a list](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=J1tyaSl7SSAKMmJ7X1clLitfXzBlPSlcXywxPlwwLVgrOiozPComfXtfLDIvPH13Mi0hCntJJyxTfSYKfWZJOzsnXQ&input=MTU5Ng) of super folding numbers up to a given number.
Golfing attempts can be seen [here](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=ZSNyaTJie19XJS4rX3syPX0lXywsX1clLj0uXjp8MSQsMT18IX17XywyLzx9dzItIQplI3JpMmJ7X1clLitfezI9fSVfLDpBLF9XJS49Ll5BMT0rOnwhfXtBMi88fXcyLSEKZSNyaTJie19XJS4rX3syPX0lXywsX1clLj0uXl8sMT0rOnwhfXtfLDIvPH13Mi0hCmUjcmkyYntfVyUuK19fMGU9MiVcXywxPVwwLVgrOioyPnx8IX17XywyLzx9dzItIQogIHJpMmJ7X1clLitfXzBlPSlcXywxPlwwLVgrOiozPComfXtfLDIvPH13Mi0h&input=MTU5Ng).

---

The code breaks down to the following phases:

```
ri2b                e# get input in binary
{                   e# While fold is legal
 _W%.+_             e#   "fold" the whole number onto itself
 _0e=)\             e#   count zeros and add 1 (I)
 _,1>\              e#   size check, leave 0 if singleton (II)*
 0-X+:*3<           e#   product of 2s, leave 0 if too many (III)
 *&                 e#   (II AND III) AND parity of I
}{                  e# Do
 _,2/<              e#   slice opposite to the actual fold**
}w                  e# End while
2-!                 e# return 1 if "fold" ended in all 2s
```

**EDIT:** This version more or less takes a [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Formal_notation) approach to the previous version.

**The problem with running on singletons is that we get stuck with an empty string after the slice.*

*** If a binary number is super folding, its mirror image (with leading 0s if needed) is. This saves a byte over taking the right half.*

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 149 bytes

```
f=(i,n=i.toString(2),l=n.length,m=l/2|0)=>/^1*$/.test(n)?1:/[^01]/.test(n)|!+n[m]&l?0:f(0,+n.slice(0,m)+ +n.slice(m+l%2).split``.reverse().join``+"")
```

Defines a recursive function.

### Explanation:

```
f=(i                       //Defines the function: i is input
,n=i.toString(2)           //n is the current number
,l=n.length                //l is the length of the number,
,m=l/2|0)=>                //m is the index of the center character
/^1*$/.test(n)?1:          //returns 1 if the number is all ones
/[^01]/.test(n)            //returns 0 if the number has any chars other than 0 or 1
|!+n[m]&l?0:               //or if the middle char is 0
f(0,+n.slice(0,m)+ +n.slice(m+l%2).split``.reverse().join``+"")
                           //otherwise recurses using the first half of the number plus the second half
```

Comment: `m=l>>1`, `/2/.test(n)`, `n.slice(l-m)` (or slice the reversed string). I think if you switch the failure and success cases then you can use `/0/.test(n)?f(...):1`.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>113</s> <s>109</s> 108 bytes

```js
f=(n,[h,...r]=n.toString(2),b='')=>++n&-n-n?h?f(2,r,r[0]?b+(h- -r.pop()):+h?b:2):!isNaN(n=+('0b'+b))&&f(n):1
```

#### Formatted and commented

```js
f = (                               // given:
  n,                                // - n = integer to process
  [h, ...r] = n.toString(2),        // - h = highest bit, r = remaining low bits
  b = ''                            // - b = folded binary string
) =>                                //
  ++n & -n - n ?                    // if n is not of the form 2^N - 1:
    h ?                             //   if there's still at least one bit to process:
      f(                            //     do a recursive call with:
        2,                          //     - n = 2 to make the 2^N - 1 test fail
        r,                          //     - r = remaining bits
        r[0] ?                      //     - if there's at least one remaining low bit:
          b + (h - -r.pop())        //       append sum of highest bit + lowest bit to b
        : +h ? b : 2                //       else, h is the middle bit: let b unchanged
      )                             //       if it is set or force error if it's not
    : !isNaN(n = +('0b' + b)) &&    //   else, if b is a valid binary string:
      f(n)                          //     relaunch the entire process on it
  : 1                               // else: n is a super folding number -> success
```

#### Demo

```js
f=(n,[h,...r]=n.toString(2),b='')=>++n&-n-n?h?f(2,r,r[0]?b+(h- -r.pop()):+h?b:2):!isNaN(n=+('0b'+b))&&f(n):1

// testing integers in [1 .. 99]
for(var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
  f(i) && console.log(i);
}

// testing integers in [1500 .. 1599]
for(var i = 1500; i < 1600; i++) {
  f(i) && console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, <s>71</s> 70 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Give number on STDIN

`superfolding.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$_=sprintf"%b",$_;s%.%/\G0$/?2:/.\B/g&&$&+chop%eg while/0/>/2/;$_=!$&
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 151 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,r=0:f(bin(n)[2:],'')if r<''else(r==''and{'1'}==set(n)or(n in'1'and f(r,'')+2)or n!='0'and'11'!=n[0]+n[-1]and f(n[1:-1],r+max(n[0],n[-1])))%2
```

**[ideone](http://ideone.com/QvjtZn)**

A doubly-recursive function which takes an integer, `n`, and returns `0` or `1`.

A variable `r` is maintained to allow both the result of folding and to know if we currently: have an integer (first only); have a new binary string to try to fold (outer); or are folding (inner).

On the first pass `n` is and integer, which is `<''` in Python 2 so the recursion starts by casting to a binary string.

The next execution has `r=''` and so the test `{'1'}==set(n)` is executed to check for a continuous string of `1`s (the RHS cannot be `{n}` as we may need to pass this point later with `r=''` and an empty `n` when that would be a dictionary which wont equal `{'1'}`, a set).

If this is not satisfied the inner tail criteria is tested for (even if unnecessary): if `n in'1'` will evaluate to True when `n` is an empty string or a single `1`, whereupon a new outer recursion is begun by placing `r`, by the then folded, binary string into `n` and `''` into `r`. The literal `2` is added to the result of this function call to allow no fall through to the next part (to the right of a logical `or`) that is corrected later.

If that is not a truthy value (all non-zero integers are truthy in Python) the outer tail recursion criteria is tested for: `n!=0` excludes the case with a middle `0` and the outer two characters are tested they do not sum to `2` by the string concatenation `'11'!=n[0]+n[-1]`; if these both hold true the outer bits are discarded from `n` with `n[1:-1]`, and then a `1` is appended to `r` if there is one on the outside otherwise a `0` is, using the fact that `'1'>'0'` in Python with `max(n[0],n[-1])`.

Finally the addition of `2` at each inner recursion is corrected with `%2`.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 113 bytes

```
for($n=$argv[1];$n!=$c;$n=($a=$n>>.5+$e)|($b=$n&$c=(1<<$e/=2)-1))if($a&$b||($e=1+log($n,2))&!(1&$n>>$e/2))die(1);
```

exits with error (code `1`) if argument is not super-folding, code `0` else. Run with `-r`.
Input `0` will return true (code `0`).

**breakdown**

```
for($n=$argv[1];            
    $n!=$c;                 // loop while $n is != mask
                            // (first iteration: $c is null)
    $n=                     // add left half and right half to new number
        ($a=$n>>.5+$e)      // 7. $a=left half
        |
        ($b=$n&             // 6. $b=right half
            $c=(1<<$e/=2)-1 // 5. $c=mask for right half
        )
)
    if($a&$b                // 1. if any bit is set in both halves
                            // (first iteration: $a and $b are null -> no bits set)
        ||                  // or
        ($e=1+log($n,2))    // 2. get length of number
        &
        !(1&$n>>$e/2)       // 3. if the middle bit is not set -> 1
                            // 4. tests bit 0 in length --> and if length is odd
    )
    die(1);                 // -- exit with error
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 197 Bytes

```
function f($b){if(!$b)return;if(!strpos($b,"0"))return 1;for($n="",$i=0;$i<($l=strlen($b))>>1;)$n.=$b[$i]+$b[$l-++$i];if($l%2&&!$b[$i]||strstr($n,"2"))return;return f($n);}echo f(decbin($argv[1]));
```

Expanded

```
function f($b){
    if(!$b)return; # remove 0
    if(!strpos($b,"0"))return 1; # say okay alternative preg_match("#^1+$#",$b)
    for($n="",$i=0;$i<($l=strlen($b))>>1;)$n.=$b[$i]+$b[$l-++$i]; #add first half and second reverse
    if($l%2&&!$b[$i]||strstr($n,"2"))return; #if middle == zero or in new string is a 2 then it's not a number that we search
    return f($n); #recursive beginning
}
echo f(decbin($argv[1]));
```

True values < 10000

> 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20, 22, 28, 31, 34, 38, 42, 48, 52, 56, 63, 74, 78, 90, 104, 108, 120, 127, 128, 130, 132, 142, 150, 160, 170, 178, 192, 204, 212, 232, 240, 255, 272, 274, 276, 286, 310, 336, 346, 370, 400, 412, 436, 472, 496, 511, 516, 518, 524, 542, 558, 580, 598, 614, 640, 642, 648, 666, 682, 704, 722, 738, 772, 796, 812, 852, 868, 896, 920, 936, 976, 992, 1023, 1060, 1062, 1068, 1086, 1134, 1188, 1206, 1254, 1312, 1314, 1320, 1338, 1386, 1440, 1458, 1506, 1572, 1596, 1644, 1716, 1764, 1824, 1848, 1896, 1968, 2016, 2047, 2050, 2054, 2058, 2064, 2068, 2072, 2110, 2142, 2176, 2180, 2184, 2222, 2254, 2306, 2320, 2358, 2390, 2432, 2470, 2502, 2562, 2576, 2618, 2650, 2688, 2730, 2762, 2866, 2898, 2978, 3010, 3072, 3076, 3080, 3132, 3164, 3244, 3276, 3328, 3380, 3412, 3492, 3524, 3584, 3640, 3672, 3752, 3784, 3888, 3920, 4000, 4032, 4095, 4162, 4166, 4170, 4176, 4180, 4184, 4222, 4318, 4416, 4420, 4424, 4462, 4558, 4674, 4688, 4726, 4822, 4928, 4966, 5062, 5186, 5200, 5242, 5338, 5440, 5482, 5578, 5746, 5842, 5986, 6082, 6208, 6212, 6216, 6268, 6364, 6508, 6604, 6720, 6772, 6868, 7012, 7108, 7232, 7288, 7384, 7528, 7624, 7792, 7888, 8032, 8128, 8191, 8202, 8206, 8218, 8232, 8236, 8248, 8318, 8382, 8456, 8460, 8472, 8542, 8606, 8714, 8744, 8814, 8878, 8968, 9038, 9102, 9218, 9222, 9234, 9248, 9252, 9264, 9334, 9398, 9472, 9476, 9488, 9558, 9622, 9730, 9760, 9830, 9894, 9984